# Does the wording "each land" also include Basic Lands?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Bountiful Harvest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bountiful%20Harvest). It's a Sorcery that reads "You gain l life for each land you control."

Does this refer to only cards that say Land and not Basic Land, or does it count for both?

Comment: [This explanation](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/8024/1910) might be helpful.

Answer (score 9):

A Basic Land is still a land. Any card with "Land" in the type line is a land.

> 205.1. The type line is printed directly below the illustration. It contains the card's card type(s). It also contains the card's subtype(s) and supertype(s), if applicable.
>
> 205.2a The card types are artifact, creature, enchantment, instant, land, plane, planeswalker, sorcery, tribal, and vanguard. See section 3,"Card Types."
>
> 305.5. Land subtypes are always a single word and are listed after a long dash. Land subtypes are also called land types. Lands may have multiple subtypes. See rule 205.3i for the complete list of land types.
>
> **Example:** "Basic Land — Mountain"means the card is a land with the subtype Mountain.

Comment: The question is do I get a life point for ever basic land.  My opponent did not allow me to gain a life point for ever basic-land card.

Comment: @user4893 Like the answer says, basic lands are lands. So are nonbasic lands. You get a point of life for each land you control, no matter what kind it is.

Comment: good, then I wonder why this card only got a 1 star rating :)

Comment: @user4893 This card only has a 1 star rating because life gain, in itself, does not win games. This is one of the first lessons of the aspiring magic player. All life gain by itself does is slow down how fast you lose the game. This particular card is expensive for its effect.

Comment: Lifegain can be effective to the extent that it buys you time, just like bounce or tap spells. It needs to be cheap and gain you a _lot_ of life though. Like [Rest for the Weary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=189180) in a deck that's just trying to survive til turn 4, or [Gnaw to the Bone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247420) in a self-milling Limited deck.

Comment: The one exception to the "life gain only buys time" rule is if you're playing against burn because then your spells are essentially countering their spells. For instance if my opponent bolts me in the face then I gain 3 life I essentially countered their lightning bolt.

Comment: @LeeAbraham Real burn decks are packed with cards like Skullcrack, Flames of the Blood Hand, and Sulfuric Vortex, though. I've had more success with lifegain against RDW than actual Burn.

Answer (score 5):

*Land* is short for *land permanent*, which means *permanent that has "land" as one of its types*.

It doesn't matter what supertypes it might have, if any. For example, both [Forest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Forest) (basic) and [Academy Ruins](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Academy%20Ruins) (legendary) match.

It doesn't matter what other types it might have, if any. For example, both [Dryad Arbor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dryad%20Arbor) (creature) and [Tree of Tales](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tree%20of%20Tales) (artifact) match.

It doesn't matter what subtypes it might have, if any. For example, both [Forest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Forest) (forest) and [Golgari Guildgate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Golgari%20Guildgate) (gate) match.

So, if you have a three Forests and one Golgari Guildgate, you'll gain four life.